# Aggregating Data around an Intervention

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to track conflict data before and after an intervention. The intervention occurs on a specific date, and I want to aggregate the number of conflict events and casualties that occur within a country in each of the 25 weeks before and after the intervention. Here's a dput output of a subset of my data. In this example, I'm only looking at Burundi, but my actual dataset includes several other countries.

```
conflict_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      country = c(
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi",
        "Burundi"
      ),
      year = structure(
        c(
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L,
          5L
        ),
        levels = c(
          "1989",
          "1990",
          "1991",
          "1992",
          "1993",
          "1994",
          "1995",
          "1996",
          "1997",
          "1998",
          "1999",
          "2000",
          "2001",
          "2002",
          "2003",
          "2004",
          "2005",
          "2006",
          "2007",
          "2008",
          "2009",
          "2010",
          "2011",
          "2012",
          "2013",
          "2014",
          "2015",
          "2016",
          "2017",
          "2018",
          "2019",
          "2020",
          "2021",
          "2022"
        ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      day = 283:311,
      conflict_date = structure(
        c(
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          8694,
          8695,
          8696,
          8697,
          8698,
          NA,
          8700,
          8701,
          NA,
          NA,
          8704,
          NA,
          NA,
          NA,
          8708,
          NA,
          NA,
          8711
        ),
        class = "Date"
      ),
      conflict_event_count = c(
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        73L,
        41L,
        20L,
        9L,
        7L,
        0L,
        6L,
        1L,
        0L,
        0L,
        1L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        1L,
        0L,
        0L,
        1L
      ),
      sum_casualties = c(
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        2293L,
        748L,
        173L,
        254L,
        185L,
        0L,
        172L,
        20L,
        0L,
        0L,
        1L,
        0L,
        0L,
        0L,
        3L,
        0L,
        0L,
        10L
      ),
      intervention.date = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        "1993-10-24",
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 237686:237714, class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to put the weekly sums into another dataset to merge later. In the code I tried, I call this dataset conflict_data_aggregated. I'd like to have it look something like the below image, but with many more rows for other countries and columns for each of the 25 weeks before and after the intervention day. The sums for weekly conflict events are under their respective column headers. For example, week1_pre_event_total shows the sum of conflict events in the week prior to the intervention. The same for the other weeks.
[image]

Here is my code. The data is arranged by days, but I'm aggregating by week, so I'm trying to sum both conflict events and casualties by every seven days (e.g., Week 1 is Day 1 thru Day 7; Week 2 is Day 8 thru Day 14; Week 3 is Day 15 thru Day 21, and so on). In the below code, I only tried to get the sum total for conflict events and casualties for the one week prior to the intervention (Day -1 thru Day -7), but eventually, I'd like to add the additional weeks.

```
# Function to indicate treatment days and aggregate data
aggregate_treatment_data <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(treatment = ifelse(!is.na(date.qualification), 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(treatment == 1) %>%
    group_by(country, year, day) %>%
    summarise(
      week1_pre_event_total = sum(conflict_event_count[(which(treatment == 1) - 7):(which(treatment == 1) - 1)], na.rm = TRUE),
      week1_pre_casualties = sum(sum_casualties[(which(treatment == 1) - 7):(which(treatment == 1) - 1)], na.rm = TRUE)
    )
}

# Create a new conflict dataset with aggregated data for 1 week before the treatment
conflict_data_aggregated <- aggregate_treatment_data(conflict_data)
```

Any advice on how to aggregate the sums by week around the intervention would be amazing. I apologize for the rambling. If anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I also forgot to mention that in the above code, I just tried to aggregate the totals for the week prior to intervention. It was just a practice run to figure out the logic.

Comment: Hi Dylan Forrester, welcome to SO. Please do not add data as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, run `dput(conflict_data)` or `dput(head(conflict_data), 20)` if your df is large and copy the result into your question. Do the same for your conflict_data_aggregated too. Thanks

Comment: I voted to close because you haven't followed L Tyrone's (great) advice. Please swap out your screenshots for actual data

Comment: also providing a sample expected response would go a long way. I have a vague idea of what I *think* you want, but there's every chance I create something and you say something along the lines of, "actually I was looking for x.."

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I believe you are looking for. If not, then please comment, or use it as a starting point towards your desired output:

```
# load libraries
library(tidyverse) 

# make sampling reproducible
set.seed(0)

# create a sample dataset, since you didn't give us one.
# in this one, there's three countries, "Applonia", "Banania", and "Cocovia",
# and data on conflict events for exactly 26 weeks before and after the intervention date, on the 183rd day (26 weeks plus one)
df <- data.frame(
    country = rep(c("Applonia", "Banania", "Cocovia"), each = (52*7) + 1),
    conflict_events = sample(0:100, 3 * ((52*7) + 1), replace = TRUE),
    deaths = sample(0:100, 3 * ((52*7) + 1), replace = TRUE),
    intervention = (26*7) + 1)

# we add a day column, then figure out the week every day is in (we need to do an ifelse, because we always want the more extreme rounding - rounding down when negative and up when positive)
new_df <- df |> mutate(day = rep(1:((52*7) + 1), 3),
             week = ifelse(intervention > day, floor((day - intervention) /7),  ceiling((day - intervention) /7)))

# now we simply use summarise and pivot wider
new_df |> 
  summarise(across(c(conflict_events, deaths), \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)), .by = c(country, week)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = week, values_from = c(conflict_events, deaths))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 107
  country  `conflict_events_-26` `conflict_events_-25` `conflict_events_-24`
  <chr>                    <int>                 <int>                 <int>
1 Applonia                   279                   402                   402
2 Banania                    298                   359                   491
3 Cocovia                    364                   279                   385
# ℹ 103 more variables: `conflict_events_-23` <int>,
#   `conflict_events_-22` <int>, `conflict_events_-21` <int>,
#   `conflict_events_-20` <int>, `conflict_events_-19` <int>,
#   `conflict_events_-18` <int>, `conflict_events_-17` <int>,
#   `conflict_events_-16` <int>, `conflict_events_-15` <int>,
#   `conflict_events_-14` <int>, `conflict_events_-13` <int>,
#   `conflict_events_-12` <int>, `conflict_events_-11` <int>, …
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much, Mark! Sorry about not initially providing any data. Thanks for still answering the question.

Comment: no stress, glad I could help